# Edit all default file type applications?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, defaults

As a developer I have Xcode installed, which also seems to make itself the default for a bunch of different filetypes. Similarly, VLC seems to make itself the default for any .zip or .rar file. I've tried to update these through the Open With dialog, but they either don't apply or they get reset whenever an app gets updated.

Is there a piece of software that will let me manage these all from one screen?

There is [this related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263867/where-are-default-apps-for-file-types-listed), but it doesn't answer my specific requirement to have it all in one screen. I simply want one piece of software that will list all file types that have a default assigned, let me change which app is assigned, and then monitor changes and re-apply my own preferences whenever it gets changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) gets close to what I need. Sadly lacks a search box (or integration into the settings search) and grouping for file types, but it's close.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.